# Error with Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I'm computing a quantity using its Fourier transform. However, I don't think what I'm getting makes sense. This is what I have

$$ \Delta E = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dE}{dt} dt = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} i \omega Ẽ(\omega) e^{i \omega t} \frac{d \omega}{2 \pi} dt = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}i \omega Ẽ(\omega) \delta(\omega) = 0. $$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You made the assumption $$\lim_{\omega\to0}i\omega\tilde{E}(\omega) =0$$ when this is not a true statement.

Comment: @NinadMunshi ah true. But even assuming it was. Would the result be zero?

Comment: ...yes? I'm not sure what you're asking. Of course when you take the assumption that makes your statement true, the statement becomes true

Comment: what im asking is if the result is always null when that limit is 0. the point is that i dont know if my statement is true or if im doing something wrong

Comment: Of course it is, you just proved that.  It is not an error.

Comment: that was it. i was surprised by it.thanks

Comment: You interchanged the order of integration.  How was this justified?